# What happened to UNSC Forward Unto Dawn crew during Halo 3 last missions?

Tags: halo

Chief and Arbiter "board" empty ship, that was parked by Sgt. Johnson.
What happened to 728 crew members? Are they dead or assimilated by the Flood?

Comment: The Forward Unto Dawn is alluded to the mini web series Halo4: Forward Unto Dawn that became a movie put up on Netflix in 2013. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_4:_Forward_Unto_Dawn

Comment: Those mini web series are taking place before events of Halo 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know for sure there were a number of humans that made it through the battle of the Ark, as Johnson mentions them at the beginning of the second to last level:

> "Chief? I'll round up our survivors and fall back to the Dawn. Arbiter will do the same with the Elites."

Shipmaster Rtas 'Vadum mentions them again at the beginning of the last level when he asks if the Arbiter really wants to do the next part:

> "We are aboard. Humans, and Elites. Will you not come with us brother?"
>
> "No, this is our fight. And I will see it finished."

Right after this, Cortana emphasizes that they're trying to keep safe:

> "Johnson, do you have the frigate?"
>
> "Yes ma'am. I'll land her as close to the control room as I can."
>
> "Safe is better than close, sergeant major"
>
> "Roger that. And ma'am, it's good to have you back"
>
> "Halo... it's so new, unfinished. I'm not exactly sure what will happen when we fire it."

As only Master Chief, the Arbiter, and Johnson* are chancing Flood exposure, it seems that the other survivors are staying safe by not taking unnecessary risks, like heading to a potential Flood infestation or running from an uncertain superweapon activation at the last minute.

With those facts in mind, I've always assumed that the ship's crew had transferred over to one of the Elite ships before this operation. The Shipmaster does say humans are aboard. Pelicans can also manage a short distance in space, and it isn't a long shot to the portal that comes out on Earth. But it seems quite unlikely that they were on the *Dawn* during the last mission, as we don't see any sign of them during the level or epilogue, nor any evidence that the Flood swarmed the ship in the last minutes. I'm sure the final veterans of the war are safe.

*Johnson is immune or otherwise undesirable to the Flood as a result of some checkered medical history. "They swarmed all over us. Jenkins and Keyes were taken... but I guess I didn't taste too good... They 'passed me up' like I was undercooked spinach at a turkey dinner." - *First Strike*, Chapter 6